# How to do two-way binding in Ag-grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

### Is it possible to do a two way binding in vanilla Javascript?

I am trying to do a two-way data binding in ag-grid and currently, I am only displaying the data via checkbox and no binding:

```
columnDefs: [
   {headerName: "HeaderA",field: "fieldA", width: 150, editable: true,
    cellRenderer: params => {
        return `<input type='checkbox' ${params.value == 'Y' ? 'checked' : ''} />`
    }
   }
]
```

I would like to do a two-way data binding for this checkbox so that by checking the checkbox, I am changing the cell-value as well.

At the moment, my grid performs very similar to this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/cV5wFLY4nnyQgVIcnGrF?p=preview

[You can click on the checkbox, but if you double-click on the cell itself to see the cell-value, you'll see that the cell-value hasn't changed]

I would grealy appreciate any help/advice!

Comment: Yes.  Read up on 'Event Listener' -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener

Comment: refer this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490004/2-way-data-binding-in-javascript

Comment: "pure JavaScript" doesn't have anything to do with the DOM: what you mean is *standard DOM APIs*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: the question no longer references AngularJS, but this answer still does.

Yes, it's possible.  AngularJS uses vanilla Javascript to achieve the two-way bindings, so that we don't have to.

However, if you are using the AngularJS framework then you should probably use the tools it already offers.

If you want to perform binding without using the built-in directives, e.g. `ng-model`, `ng-bind`, and `{{}}`, consider `$scope.$watch` and `$scope.$watchCollection`, these AngularJS methods are what the built-in AngularJS directives use to set up binding.

If you are using components, use `$onChanges` or `$doCheck`.

Comment: `$scope.$watch` works because it's in the context of Angular; no browser-native DOM API knows what that means.

Comment: Indeed, but I don't believe he actually needs to use vanilla Javascript here, based on this and the other question he just asked.  I think the question might be: how to achieve binding outside of the built-in directives.