# How to update input's value by updating object's property from the code thanks to a proxy?

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, proxy

I am trying to make a simple data binding system between an object and an input, thanks to a proxy.

---

Here's the variables I create:

- `obj`, a simple object with a `title` property.
- `titleInput`, the `<input#title>` DOMElement.
- `objProxy`, a Proxy object instance that wraps `obj`.

---

Then, two behaviors I am working on:

- When the input's value changes, the new value needs to be affected to the object's property.
- When the object's property changes, the new value needs to update the input's value.

The first part is working great: attaching an event listener to the input that updates the proxy's corresponding property was enough.

The second one, however, is not working as I expected. See the following code snippet:

```js
// variables
const obj = {
    title: 'my title'
  },
  titleInput = document.querySelector('#title');
  
// proxy
const objProxy = new Proxy(obj, {
  get: (obj, prop) => (Reflect.get(obj, prop)),
  set: (obj, prop, val) => {
    if (prop === 'title') titleInput.value = val;
  
    return Reflect.set(obj, prop, val);
  }
});

// input event listener
titleInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
  objProxy.title = titleInput.value;
  
  log('Input update');
});

// initialization
titleInput.value = obj.title;

// start
log('Init log');

objProxy.title = 'title from objProxy';
log('objProxy code update');

obj.title = 'title from obj';
log('obj code update');

// log function
function log(mess) {
  console.log('');
  console.log(`---${mess}---`);
  console.log('obj.title:', obj.title);
  console.log('objProxy.title:', objProxy.title);
  console.log('<#title> value:', titleInput.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="title" type="text">
```

Of course, affecting directly to `objProxy.title` works, and updates the input's value.

But I expected that affecting to `obj.title` would update the input's value too. And that's not the case, even if `objProxy.title` changes as we can see in the logs.

**How to update input's value by updating object's property from the code thanks to a proxy?**

More precisely, is it possible by writing `obj.title = X;`?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490004/2-way-data-binding-in-javascript

Comment: @AsukaSong - The answers of the question you linked are simple solutions to achieve it, but I see no mention about proxies. But maybe I am heading the wrong way?

Comment: @JamesWasson - I get it. So what I want to achieve will not be possible with by the only usage of proxies. Thanks for your comment (which should be an answer).

Comment: comment deleted and moved to answer section -- sorry about that. @KévinBibollet yes it's not possible: unless you only store references to the proxy in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems to be working as intended here. In a little more detail -- the proxy code is not ran when setting the obj.title because it is not a proxy. You are directly setting the value on the object itself. Proxies are basically meant to wrap the object then you should only use the proxy reference not the actual object itself. There is no real way around this restriction because it is inherent to the proxy and was designed that way.