# No explicit Data binding in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tom Occhino said in his presentation that there is **"No Explicit Data Binding"** especially in React.js.

Check out the presentation video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxVg_s8xAms&t=511s) and go to 7:30 minute where he said that before.

Why there is **"No explicit data binding"** in React JS?

Comment: What do you mean by “explicit data binding”?

Comment: There is no need for binding the methods or variables to the respective class. It is directly bound to the class in explicit data binding.

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by that. Methods, at least, *do* need to be "bound" if they’re being used outside the instance context, e.g., an event handler. Unclear what you’re saying with regards to variables.

Comment: My bad, Can you explain to me both explicit data binding in general and no explicit data binding in react? or any useful link which explains both?

Comment: *I* can’t; it’s not a term I’m familiar with beyond using `bind` "manually" or via arrow functions to ensure proper `this` context. That’s JS, though, not just React. That’s why I asked what you meant by it.

Comment: Now I have understood with explicit data binding in JS. But Tom Occhino said in the presentation that "No explicit data binding" in react. Check the presentation video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxVg_s8xAms&t=494s). (7:30 exact)

Comment: @DaveNewton e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490004/2-way-data-binding-in-javascript

Comment: @JaredSmith So “explicit binding” is just two-way data binding? IMO “explicit binding” is orthogonal; directionality seems like a different concept. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thank you people for helping me for understanding this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would tell you, that's a very old video, if you're learning React I would totally recommend you to find an actual one, as react has changed a lot since then. If you already know react tho, it's nice to understand its roots and how/why it works that way under the hood.

Now, about "explicit data binding". I think the point of that term in this presentation was to compare React with other frameworks where you need to "explicitly bind the data source to the dom node" for them to have 2-way interaction. That is, if the dom changes (user input) change the data accordingly (update the variable) and if the data changes (let's say an ajax call brought some remote data) change the dom acordingly (update the text in the dom node).

In other frameworks you need to declare this binding with some code, and the events on both side would trigger a change in the other side.

So, why would he say that react does not have this bindings since you can see this same behaviour with the information flowing bidirectionally.

Well, conceptualy the same thing is happening, a change in either end would trigger a change in the other. However, how this is achieved is what changes.
In react there is no method that updates one input dom node especifically when there's a change in a variable. Instead a whole re-render is triggered, calculating the new markup that will be inserted in the dom. This markup (the string containing html) will have the input with the new data represented as `value="data"` and thus changing what you can see in the dom. But the code that executed when the variable changed had no relation at all with the dom node (there was no binding between them).
And the other way around when you set an event listener to change a variable when the input changes, react will not bind any event listener to that dom node, instead it will have an event listener at the top most node, hearing for any change in the whole dom tree and notify you acordingly if the source of the event was the input you were insterested in. But note here that there was no event listener in the exact node you wanted to hear for changes, so there was no explicit binding between the dom node and your code.

That said. I think this is of no importance if you are new to javascript frameworks and may even confuse a little bit. So don't try too hard to understand this concept if it's not already clear, unless you are comparing this behaviour with another framework you are familiar with. Just keep practicing and the explanation above will just be natural and obvious to you once you have written some react forms.

Comment: Thanks for a bunch of information. It's a well-learned answer. I appreciate it. Let me know if I understood enough from your answer. _React re-render the whole DOM if any input dom node changes unlike in other frameworks, it renders only those dom node whose input dom node changes(explicit data binding). This makes React different from other frameworks._

Comment: Well, conceptually kindda. Literally, not really. Replacing the whole dom on each render would be extremely expensive and slow. So internally react has algorithms to intelligently decide what has changed in the dom and replace only what needs to be replaced. To deeply understand how this is decided read about react's virtual dom, React's rendering and pure components.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll keep learning more on this concept.